# Is there a way to calculate the mixed color (in RGB) from n (n>1) RGBA colors in a specified order in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, colors

Say I have a svg like this:

```
<svg>
  <rect id="background" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="rgba(10,10,10,1)" />    
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="100" height="100" fill="rgba(255,125,0,.25)" />
  <rect x="25" y="25" width="100" height="100" fill="rgba(0,125,0,.55)" />
  <rect x="45" y="45" width="100" height="100" fill="rgba(255,225,25,.66)" />
</svg>
```

It will rendered as:

[image]

How can I get the RGB color of this by JavaScript calculation?
(I got the result `(178,178,18)` by using a color picker tool.

[image]

I am looking for some function like this:

```
function getMixedRGBByColors(bg_color_in_rgb, [colors_in_rgba_arr]) {
  // bg_color_in_rgb defines the background color, it's not transaparent
  // colors_in_rgba_arr is the array of the
  //   colors above the background, in a specific order
  //   (it needs to be an array because changing the order
  //    will change the outcome)

  ....
};

// Usage:

getMixedRGBByColors(
  "10,10,10"
  [    
    "255,125,0,.25",
    "0,125,0,.55",
    "255,255,25,.66"
  ]);
```

Comment: IIRC SVG documentation has the formula to calculate the different mixes. For intuitive mixing you should transform R*G*B* (so gamma corrected) into (linear) RGB, then the colour are additive, and you can then transform back. Or you will find some good approximation (but not intuitive formula), because the high usage of R*G*B* (and to use integer math)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Just wondering, is it possible that on different monitors it will get different results? I tried to pick up colors from the overlap on different monitors and got different results. It's quite annoying.

Comment: No calculations are done by Javascripts (and browser). OTOH such greyish colours with some tint are the worst colours: a small offset of white balance is much more noticeable. There is not much to do (but to use same white balance setting/and correct it) and ev. to calibrate the screens.

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation is that the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model is somewhat unintuitive for us humans.

And following is pretty well worked.

```
NewColor.R = Color1.R - (Color1.R - Color2.R)/2
NewColor.G = Color1.G - (Color1.G - Color2.G)/2
NewColor.B = Color1.B - (Color1.B - Color2.B)/2
```

https://github.com/benjholla/ColorMixer also will help you.